# How to add new row to UITableView in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have to make a *"todo list"* application. I have one `UITableview` class. In it are six sections. In each section there are three rows.

In every section and every single row after I want to show a "+" to add a new row in the section.

However I have to increment according to a row. For example if I have a row with name "New Detail" and I click after the "+", then the new row should be created with detail available to enter user data for that same entry.

I have been trying for three days. Please help.

Comment: you should use full stop (.) sometimes.

Comment: Do You want to add a row dynamically to a tableview?

Comment: @KAREEMMAHAMMED ye i want to add row dynamically in tableview

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581574/add-a-row-to-uitableview-for-adding-new-item and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575898/dynamically-add-a-new-row-as-add-in-uitableview-in-edit-mode Search on "add new row dynamically to UITableView"

Answer (score 2):

use below function to add row dynamically -

```
 [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
```

Comment: friend can u help me how to code for it i have one button action what to write in button action